# Who are the two witnesses in Sleepy Hollow?

Tags: tv, sleepy-hollow

In the new Sleepy Hollow TV show, it's revealed that the Mills sisters are the "two witnesses" mentioned in Revelations.
However, Jennifer Mills implies at the end of the *Lesser Key of Solomon* episode that Ichabod and Abby are the witnesses.
Granted Ichabod saw the white trees as Jennifer and Abbey did but shouldn't all three be the witnesses now?
So, who are the witnesses supposed to be?

Comment: I'm not sure it was ever actually stated that Jennifer Mills was a witness, was it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was stated that who ever saw the 4 white trees are the witnesses. So initially it was Abby and Jennifer who saw the trees. And I figured Crane would assist. But then Crane sees the trees too, creating the 3 way split. So, I guess a related question is: what makes Jennifer think she's not a witness? Besides the out of universe answer that she's not one of the lead characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most recent introductions to the show indicate the Witnesses to the Apocalypse are indeed historian and former spy, Icabod Crane and Lieutenant Abigail Mills. It appears that Jennifer will be providing local support and act as a consultant to the Witnesses.

Comment: That's the out of universe answer -  which is fine; I didn't specify. So, what's the in universe answer? How does Jennifer know she's not a witness, even though she was one of the first to see the trees?

Comment: She doesn't appear to know for certain but she also does not appear to WANT to be a witness. Having the knowledge she has already appears to be more involved than she appears to want to be. She seems quite content to avoid any further involvement especially since Revelations indicates the Witnesses, after seeing the arrival of the Horsemen will die... (Talk about motivation to prevent their arrival...)

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up on Thaddeus' (correct) answer, Crane identifies himself as the first witness and Abby as the second quite explicitly in the pilot episode. Near the end of the episode, they have this exchange:

> **Crane**: In my dream, Katrina referred to me as "the first witness"
>
> **Mills**: Revelations
>
> **Crane**: This speaks of two witnesses, brought together for a seven year period of Tribulation [...]
>
> **Mills**: You think that's us.